# Session is not being saved in express-session

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session

I'm studying about HTTPS.
I'm trying to make login/logout function. To this function, I saved userId in session  when I login through POST method. After that, I tried to use GET method to get user information for next components. But there is no userId in session.
I totally have no idea. I tried to use session.save(). How to save something in session?

```
//login.js
const { Users } = require('../../models');

module.exports = {
  post: async (req, res) => {
 
    const userInfo = await Users.findOne({
      where: { userId: req.body.userId, password: req.body.password },
    });
    
    if (!userInfo) {
      // your code here
      res.send({ message : `not authorized` })
      
    } else {
      
      req.session.userId= userInfo.userId
      res.send({ message :`ok` })
    
      
    }
  }
}
```

```
//userinfo.js

const { Users } = require('../../models');

module.exports = {
  get: async (req, res) => {

    console.log(req.session) // I can't read userId here.
    if (!req.session.userId) {
     
      res.status(400).send({ message : `not authorized` })
    } else {
      
      let result = await Users.findOne({
        where: { userId: req.session.userId },
      })

      res.status(200).send({userId : result.userId, email : result.email, message : 'ok'})
    }
  },
};
```

```
//index.js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const session = require('express-session');
const logger = require('morgan');
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');
const usersRouter = require('./routes/user');

const app = express();

const FILL_ME_IN = 'FILL_ME_IN';

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;

app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'practice',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
      domain: 'localhost',
      path: '/',
      maxAge: 24 * 6 * 60 * 10000,
      sameSite: 'none',
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: true,
    },
  })
);
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(cors());
/**
 * POST https://localhost:4000/users/login,
 * POST https://localhost:4000/users/logout,
 * GET https://localhost:4000/users/userinfo
 */
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

let server;

if (fs.existsSync("./key.pem") && fs.existsSync("./cert.pem")) {
  server = https
    .createServer(
      {
        key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + `/` + 'key.pem', 'utf-8'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + `/` + 'cert.pem', 'utf-8'),
      },
      app
    )
    .listen(PORT);
} else {
  server = app.listen(PORT)
}
module.exports = server;
```

```
//components/login.js
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: '',
      password: '',
    };
    this.inputHandler = this.inputHandler.bind(this);
    this.loginRequestHandler = this.loginRequestHandler.bind(this);
  }

  inputHandler(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }

  loginRequestHandler() {
  
    let data = { userId : this.state.username, password : this.state.password }

    axios.post('https://localhost:4000/users/login', {
      userId : data.userId,
      password : data.password
    })
    .then(res => {
      
      console.log(res.config.data)
      if (res.data.message === 'ok') {
        this.props.loginHandler()
        
        axios.get('https://localhost:4000/users/userinfo', {
          session : {
            userId : res.config.data.userId
          }    
        })
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res)
          if (res.data.message === 'ok') {
            this.props.setUserInfo(res.data)
          }
        })
        
      }
      
    })

  }
    

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='loginContainer'>
        <div className='inputField'>
          <div>Username</div>
          <input
            name='username'
            onChange={(e) => this.inputHandler(e)}
            value={this.state.username}
            type='text'
          />
        </div>
        <div className='inputField'>
          <div>Password</div>
          <input
            name='password'
            onChange={(e) => this.inputHandler(e)}
            value={this.state.password}
            type='password'
          />
        </div>
        <div className='passwordField'>
          <button onClick={this.loginRequestHandler} className='loginBtn'>
            Login
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You said "I tried to use session.save()"... Yes, you should save the session after modifying.

Apart from that, you should wait the session to be saved before sending the result (i.e., you should be sure that the session has been saved before doing `res.send({ message :"ok" })`).

And finally, to answer your question:

> How to save something in session?

You should do like following:

```
req.session.userId= userInfo.userId;
        return req.session.save((err) => {
          console.log(err);
          res.send({ message :`ok` })
        });
```

Comment: No, it doesn't solve the problem.